# How to pick Tomcat context.xml parameter through SpEL expression in Java Code

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, spring-el

I am trying to get `context.xml` parameter through SpEL expresseion but I am getting `null`.

My code to get paramter is

```
public class DatabaseProperties extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Value("#{'${myConfigDirectory}'}")
    private String dbConfigPath;

    @Override
    protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException 
        Resource location = new FileSystemResource("/spring-data-access.properties");
        System.out.println("DB CONFIG PATH "+dbConfigPath);
        System.out.println("DB LOCATION + "+location.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        setLocation(location);
        super.loadProperties(props);
    }
}
```

here `dbConfigPath` is always `null`.

My configuration file is in `.xml`. here it is

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.properties.DatabaseProperties">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I need to do it so that when a `war` is deployed it should pick properties from outside war using `parameter` defined in 'context.xm' and when in `dev` it should pick from `resource` folder.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer , just declare a bean in configuration.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
          value={"classpath:/spring-data-access.properties"},
          ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class Config {

    @Value("${myConfigDirectory}}")
    private String dbConfigPath;
    /**
     * Property placeholder configurer needed to process @Value annotations
     */
     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hint: the important point is to make the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` factory method static! see http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/07/spring-bean-and-propertyplaceholderconf.html

Comment: My configuratioin is in `xml`. I need to use tomcat `context.xml` to pick properties when I deploy to tomcat and in development mode it should pick the `*.properties` file from resource folder.

What will be the configuration in `xml` for above?